# SQl Server I need to fix the error of "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know it's been asked a bunch of times but I can't seem to get the fixes I've read to solve my issue. I'm getting the SQL Server error that "the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." I changed the setting under Tools>Options>Designers>"Override connection string time- out value" to 120 seconds as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510752/how-can-i-change-the-timeout-for-a-manually-executed-query-in-sql-server) posting, but... it still times out after 30 seconds. I'm accessing the database from visual studio, working directly with it, and not with ado in client code. I'm open to suggestions... here's the query btw:

`SELECT 
       Symbol 
 FROM 
       tblSymbolsMain 
 WHERE 
       ((SELECT     dbo.LatestDateInDailyPricingVolBySymbol(tblSymbolsMain.Symbol) AS Expr1) < dbo.RecentTradingDateByNumber(5))`

In a nutshell, the goal is to return all stock symbols from a main symbols table that don't have a daily pricing data point in the pricing table for at least 5 trading days.

As always thanks in advance..

Comment: Does that query run quickly when you call it directly from a database tool such as Management Studio?

Comment: What happens when you run the query in Management Studio? What's the elapsed time to complete the query?

Comment: @DOK, HardCode I have it running now, we're at 5 min and still running.. it looks like I need better logic?

Comment: WHERE what?  That is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesnt appear to be correct ... you have `...WHERE (SELECT...)`
WHERE what?

Are you sure you are not after

`SELECT MyCols FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (...)`

OR

`SELECT MyCols FROM MyTable WHERE ID NOT IN (...)`

Where `(...)` represents another select returning some sort of ID.

Otherwise of course you'd get a timeout.  That select may return a count and `WHERE 1` can go on and on and on...

Comment: I agreed when I read your post and took another first pass at mine, but the WHERE clause should return a boolean, for each row evaluated. That function comparison compares two dates. I would think no problem...

Comment: StatsViaCsh - Fine if it involves a boolean your query is still incorrect you have to say:  `SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE myCol < (SELECT...)` that is what you are missing, currently you aren't comparing anything.

Comment: Gotcha.. so I DO need the "Select" for the comparison. You were right, it's running now but in an altered form, thanks.