# SQl Server still getting the error of "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I thought I had a sql error licked in a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885072/sql-server-i-need-to-fix-the-error-of-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elaps) just a bit ago... (Error message: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.") I'm trying to run this with the database tools in visual studio... not management studio, and not via client code/ ADO (yet). I rewrote a fairly simple query that uses a couple of custom functions... the functions as well as the parts of the query have been tested and all are running well, but the query below times out.. this does run exactly as typed in Management Studio, and takes about 4 minutes. As I mentioned in my other post, I changed the setting under Tools>Options>Designers>"Override connection string time- out value" to 120 seconds as per this posting, but... it still times out after 30 seconds. Adding the ISNULL in this latest version is the change that has it running in management studio.

```
SELECT Symbol, LatestDate
FROM (SELECT Symbol, ISNULL(dbo.LatestDateInDailyPricingVolBySymbol(Symbol), '1/1/1900') AS LatestDate FROM tblSymbolsMain) AS T2
WHERE (LatestDate < dbo.RecentTradingDateByNumber(3))
```

The general idea is to get back a subset of stock symbols that don't have a corresponding data point in my daily pricing table for at least 3 days. Any takers? Thanks all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without regards to your timeout;

Are you using the sql management console to run your query?  If so, when connecting to the database there is an options button that allows one to set the timeouts.

[image: Connection Options]

Also, if in the query window, right click and choose Query Options....

0, means unlimited, I would check these.  4 minutes is a long time, maybe the query can be refactored to run faster?

[image]

If you are running this inside of Visual Studio via C# the default command timeout is 30 seconds.  Alter it by setting the command time out:

```
SqlCommand comm= new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandTimeout = 300;
```

Comment: As I mentinoed it runs in Management Studio but takes a while... I'm trying to run it with the sql tools in visual studio 2010.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh - Must be a setting inside of VS2010 that is similiar to SQL Server Management console.  If there was code generated, it can be adjused via code, but maybe right click on the query screen, or options somewhere?  Sorry, I don't use VS2010 to run queries, just the SQL Server management console, so I am unfamiliar with those screens.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh - Looked around VS2010 a bit, I can set the connection timeout, but can't find the command timeout.  I would try with code instead of using the tool, it looks like it is using a default which cannot be easily changed.

Comment: Thanks... I hadn't looked for it until your suggestion, but there is a set of options in visual studio under tools> options> DatabaseTools. I changed it and it runs.. over the course of almost five minutes! :) It'll do for now.

Answer (score 2):

If a query takes that long of time then it is probably something wrong. I would declare a variable to store the RecentTradingDateByNumber. So it looks like this:

```
DECLARE @RecentTrandingDateByNumber DATETIME
SET @RecentTrandingDateByNumber=dbo.RecentTradingDateByNumber(3)

SELECT 
    tblSymbolsMain.Symbol, 
    MAX(tblSymbolsMain.TradeDate)
FROM 
    tblSymbolsMain
GROUP BY 
    Symbol
HAVING 
    MAX(TradeDate) < @RecentTrandingDateByNumber
```

To see the execution in management studio go to "Query/Include Actual Execution Plan".
If you also want to see the traffic of the query the numbers of select etc. You can also include the client statistics. "Query/Include client statistics"

If you want to know more information about examining the queries execution see
[here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans/)

Answer (score 1):

It concerns me that your routine takes 4 minutes to start with.  That seems like a pretty simple query assuming the functions do what they seem to do, and with indexing and appropriate table design, it should return much more quickly than that.

Have you looked at the execution plan for this query:

```
SELECT Symbol, MAX(TradeDate)
FROM tblSymbolsMain
GROUP BY Symbol
HAVING MAX(TradeDate) < dbo.RecentTradingDateByNumber(3)
```

Scalar functions can be performance problems when called repeatedly on sets with a large number of rows, and also hurt sargability.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does seem very long indeed! I have not looked at my execution plan... I'm not sure how. I had the idea of making this a stored procedure that can set the value of the function : dbo.RecentTradingDateByNumber(3) just once, but I don't know that subtle change would have it fall in line. If you have a further nudge, I'm all ears.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh In Management Studio, there is a menu option for viewing the execution plan.  There is a free ebook which will tell you how to understand what a bad execution plan looks like: http://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/sql-server-execution-plans/

Answer (score 0):

Some time I get time out. but some time it execute within seconds.
it is not advisable one whenever get time out error I had been changing the data type.

ex. if your query have criteria datetime. Change data type to just date. Other Option is Date data type to datetime data type.  I know it is not right way. but It is working to me