# Can't get difference between results of subqueries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the difference between returns of 2 subqueries. Database contains around 10000 records for each subquery. When I run the selected query, it returns error instead of result.

> [S0000][-2] Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

When running each subquery separately, it returns successfully.

```
declare @date DATETIME2, @buildingId uniqueidentifier, @companyId uniqueidentifier;
set @date = GETDATE();
set @buildingId = '24f0bd56-5361-4b9f-a04e-83f86cce1628';
set @buildingId = null;

WITH [PASSPORTS]
         AS (SELECT [PersonId],
                    CONCAT([LastName], ' ', [FirstName], ' ', [MiddleName])              AS FullName,
                    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by d.[PersonId] order by d.[Date] desc) as [Row]
             FROM [dbo].[Document] d),

     [PRIVILEGES] AS
         (SELECT p.Id AS PersonId, priv.Name AS Privileges
          FROM supo.Privilege priv
                   JOIN supo.PersonPrivilege pp ON priv.Id = pp.PrivilegeId
                   JOIN Person p ON pp.PersonId = p.Id),

     [PLACES] AS
         (SELECT r.Id AS RoomId, COUNT(*) as RoomPlaces
          FROM supo.Room r
                   JOIN supo.RoomPlace rp ON r.Id = rp.RoomId
          GROUP BY r.Id)

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.Apartment     AS RoomNumber,
                      p.Id            AS PersonId,
                      p.PersonTypeId,
                      p.WorkPlace,
                      p.WorkPosition,
                      a.Id            AS AccountId,
                      pa.Id           AS PersonAccountId,
                      pa.CompanyId    AS CompanyId,
                      a.RentDocument,
                      a.RentDate,
                      a.ClosedDate,
                      a.DateExpiring,
                      rt.Name         as RelationName,
                      a.BuildingId,

                      privs.Privileges,
                      sg.Name         AS [Group],
                      sg.TrainingPeriod,
                      p.FundingTypeId AS FundingTypeId,

                      sg.DateCreated  AS GroupDateCreated,
                      csg.ShortName   AS Institute,
                      places.RoomPlaces,
                      r.TotalSpace    AS RoomSpace,
                      c.Name          AS Citizenship,

                      ps.FullName,
                      p.Gender,
                      a.RoomId,
                      rt.IsRenter

      FROM LivingHistoryItem lhi
               JOIN Person p ON lhi.PersonId = p.Id
               JOIN Account a ON lhi.AccountId = a.Id
               JOIN supo.Room r ON a.RoomId = r.Id
               JOIN Building b ON r.BuildingId = b.Id

               LEFT JOIN PersonAccount pa ON lhi.AccountId = pa.AccountId AND lhi.PersonId = pa.PersonId
               LEFT JOIN RelationType rt ON pa.RelationTypeId = rt.Id
               LEFT JOIN [PASSPORTS] ps ON ps.PersonId = p.Id and ps.Row = 1

               LEFT JOIN [PRIVILEGES] privs ON p.Id = privs.PersonId
               LEFT JOIN [PLACES] places ON places.RoomId = r.Id
               LEFT JOIN supo.StudentGroup sg ON p.StudentGroupId = sg.Id
               LEFT JOIN Company csg ON sg.CompanyId = csg.Id
               LEFT JOIN Citizenship c ON p.CitizenshipId = c.Id

               LEFT JOIN Account a1 ON a.ProlongedAccountId = a1.Id


      WHERE CAST(lhi.DormSettleDate as date) <= @date
        AND (lhi.DormEvictionDate IS NULL OR cast(lhi.DormEvictionDate as date) > @date)
        AND (a.ClosedDate IS NULL OR CAST(a.ClosedDate as DATE) > @date)
        AND CAST(a.RentDate AS DATE) <= @date

        AND (a.ProlongedAccountId IS NULL OR CAST(a1.RentDate AS DATE) > @date)
        AND (b.Id = @buildingId OR @buildingId IS NULL)
        AND (pa.CompanyId = @companyId OR @companyId IS NULL)) t1

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.Apartment     AS RoomNumber,
                      p.Id            AS PersonId,
                      p.PersonTypeId,
                      p.WorkPlace,
                      p.WorkPosition,
                      a.Id            AS AccountId,
                      pa.Id           AS PersonAccountId,
                      pa.CompanyId    AS CompanyId,
                      a.RentDocument,
                      a.RentDate,
                      a.ClosedDate,
                      a.DateExpiring,
                      rt.Name         as RelationName,
                      a.BuildingId,

                      privs.Privileges,
                      sg.Name         AS [Group],
                      sg.TrainingPeriod,
                      p.FundingTypeId AS FundingTypeId,

                      sg.DateCreated  AS GroupDateCreated,
                      csg.ShortName   AS Institute,
                      places.RoomPlaces,
                      r.TotalSpace    AS RoomSpace,
                      c.Name          AS Citizenship,

                      ps.FullName,
                      p.Gender,
                      a.RoomId,
                      rt.IsRenter

      FROM LivingHistoryItem lhi
               JOIN Person p ON lhi.PersonId = p.Id
               JOIN Account a ON lhi.AccountId = a.Id
               JOIN supo.Room r ON a.RoomId = r.Id
               JOIN Building b ON r.BuildingId = b.Id

               JOIN PersonAccount pa ON lhi.AccountId = pa.AccountId AND lhi.PersonId = pa.PersonId
               JOIN RelationType rt ON pa.RelationTypeId = rt.Id
               LEFT JOIN [PASSPORTS] ps ON ps.PersonId = p.Id and ps.Row = 1

               LEFT JOIN [PRIVILEGES] privs ON p.Id = privs.PersonId
               LEFT JOIN [PLACES] places ON places.RoomId = r.Id
               LEFT JOIN supo.StudentGroup sg ON p.StudentGroupId = sg.Id
               LEFT JOIN Company csg ON sg.CompanyId = csg.Id
               LEFT JOIN Citizenship c ON p.CitizenshipId = c.Id

               LEFT JOIN Account a1 ON a.ProlongedAccountId = a1.Id

      WHERE CAST(lhi.DormSettleDate as date) <= @date
        AND (lhi.DormEvictionDate IS NULL OR cast(lhi.DormEvictionDate as date) > @date)
        AND (a.ClosedDate IS NULL OR CAST(a.ClosedDate as DATE) > @date)
        AND CAST(a.RentDate AS DATE) <= @date

        AND (a.ProlongedAccountId IS NULL OR CAST(a1.RentDate AS DATE) > @date)
        AND (b.Id = @buildingId OR @buildingId IS NULL)
        AND (pa.CompanyId = @companyId OR @companyId IS NULL)) t2
```

Subqueries only differ by types of joins.

Comment: Did you try googling your error? First few things that I found are [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510752/how-can-i-change-the-timeout-for-a-manually-executed-query-in-sql-server) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466818/execution-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elaps.html). Seems to me like this query would take bit longer to run as it is quite complex. So maybe, as per question I linked, you should just increase or remove) your timeout settings?

Comment: A `DISTINCT` on that many columns has a smell to it. Are you *really* likely to have 2 (or more) rows that are **exactly** identical on almost *30 columns*? If you are, I would suggest a problem with your `JOIN`s. The fact you do it twice is going to be **very** expensive. Also  why, do you `LEFT JOIN` to `Account` when `Account.RentDated` *must* have a non-`NULL`? Many of those clauses in your `WHERE` should likely be in the `ON` clauses too. For example `AND (b.Id = @buildingId OR @buildingId IS NULL)` should just be `b.ID = @buildingId` in the relevant `ON` clause.

Comment: Also, why do you `CAST` your columns to a `date` in the `WHERE`, only to implicitly convert them back to a `datetime2`? Not to mentioned, as well, that `GETDATE()` is a `datetime` not a `datetime2(7)`, so why are you not assigning `SYSDATETIME` to `@date`?

Answer (score -1):

You could insert each sub query into a temporary table then do an EXCEPT on the two temporary tables

```
SELECT *
  INTO #a
  FROM 

SELECT *
  INTO #b
  FROM 

SELECT *
  FROM #a
EXCEPT
SELECT *
  FROM #b
```